# How to delete application folder on uninstalling the app

Tags: android

When i install my app some folders are created in external storage .At the time of  uninstalling the app i need to delete all these folders.

I have tried Broadcast Receiver PACKAGE_REMOVED  but it does not work

Comment: If your users don't need acces to those folders, you could use the internal storage. more info on that here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to detect when the app is uninstalled. What PACKAGE_REMOVED does is detect when OTHER apps are uninstalled, not your app.

If you want to save files on external directory and these files be removed on uninstall the app, you should use Context.getExternalFilesDir() and the files will be removed automatically (only API 8 or higher)

Comment: How to implement the alternative possibility you are talking about ?

Comment: Context.getExternalFilesDir() will generate the required folder in Android/data/mypackage..
 
My requirement is to generate folder in SD card not inside the Android/data/mypackage folder

Comment: This folder is inside the SD card. But if you want to save your files elsewhere in the SD card (external storage) I am afraid that it will not be possible to delete when you uninstall, so it should be deleted manually